# Auto update not working

Tags: google-play-store, application-autoupdate

I have Samsung Galaxy S9 with Android 10 up to date.
In my Play store I have enabled auto update feature and it's allowed to update through wifi.
I spend a lot time on wifi so I think it should work, but when I check updates in Play store there is always cca 20 application to update. I looks like it does not work. I always update manually and it takes lot of time because there are too many apps. What could be the problem?

Comment: Since it is well-documented that you cannot schedule Google Play Updates, WiFi needs to be enabled at all times, including when the screen is off, when most devices drop the connection. Look for settings to keep WiFi enabled when device is locked or sleeping. Be especially conscious that WiFi is also not shut down by battery or performance enhancer apps. Read through some of the questions in the tag 'application-autoupdate' you added to your question. Click the tag to drill through to them.

Comment: It sounds like you aren't giving Google Play services ample time to do its job.  :) 
 Auto-update is probably working fine.  Google Play is configured to update apps when your device enters a [standby or doze state](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby).  In other words, I bet your device will update apps if you plugged it in while connected to WiFi and left it alone for a little while.